# Regex para envolver expressão console.log no find/replace do eclipse

Tags: javascript, regex, eclipse

Eu estou tentando envolver todos os `console.log();` do meu código com a `condicional if(showLog) { }`. Estava aprendendo regex e descobri que conseguia selecionar todas as expressões `console.log()` inclusive as separadas em várias linhas pela formatação do eclipse, no entanto, não consegui fazer o trecho selecionado terminar em `;`, de modo que o trecho começo de uma expressão `console.log()` até o fim do código, que terminava em `;`, ficou selecionado. Alguém saberia me dizer como faço para fazer a expressão selecionada só ir até o primeiro `;` que encontrar?

A expressão que estou usando é `console[\s]*\.log\([\s\S]*(?!\))*\);`

Infelizmente não é possível que eu poste todo o código aqui, mas colocarei abaixo exemplos em que andei testando:

```
console.log();
console.log("ok");  
console.  
log("ok");  
console  
.log("hey" +  
"guys");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar `[^;]+`, que procura "tudo" menos `;`, uma vez ou mais.

A tua regex poderia ser assim ([exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/y95drf/2/)):

```
console[\s\n\.]+log\([^;]*\);
```

Comment: Engraçado, no http://regexr.com/ funciona, no entanto no eclipse ele não encontra nenhum trecho correspondente

Comment: @GabrielC. será que tens `tab`s ? testa juntar `\t` assim: `console[\s\t\n\.]+log\([^;]*\);`

Comment: Muito obrigado! Agora está funcionando perfeitamente.